# Collapsible Header Menu or arrange buttons one below other in small screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

Below is the code for page header containing a logo image, 6 buttons and a search box. I was trying to implement collapsible class of Bootstrap and failed to do so. I want to arrange every element in header below each other in a column in small screens.

For example :-

Normal Screen - **Logo Button1 Button2.... Button6 Search**

Smaller Screen -
**Logo

Button1

Button2

.
.

Search**

Can anyone help me in this case.

```
 <!-- header section - begin -->
            <header>
                <div  class="row-fluid" style="overflow:hidden">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 pull-left">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <img class="pull-left" src="images/javabuzz_logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='home.html'">Home <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='about.html'">About Us <i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='blog.html'">Blog <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='forum.html'">Forum <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='paid.html'">Paid Projects <i class="fa fa-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='contact.html'">Contact Us <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 pull-right">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="form-group input-group" style="margin-top:15px;">
                                <input id="search" placeholder="Here you search" class="form-control"/>
                                <span id="search-icon"class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>                     
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <!-- header section - end -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bootstrap you have different columns for different screen sizes:

- col-lg = large screens (larger desktops)
- col-md = medium screens (laptops, desktops)
- col-sm = small screens (tablets)
- col-xs = extra small screens (mobiles)

If you want something on its own line, you use all columns available, that being 12, so for smaller devices you would use col-xs-12.

The code below has been changed to remove the row-fluid you have used, and instead columns have been used more, mainly for your buttons, simple to keep them in line, you may need to work on the sizing a little more for those, however everything would fall collapse into a list like format. Please see below:

```
<!-- header section - begin -->
<header>
    <div  class="row" style="overflow:hidden">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-12 pull-left">
            <img class="pull-left" src="images/javabuzz_logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='home.html'">Home <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='about.html'">About Us <i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='blog.html'">Blog <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='forum.html'">Forum <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='paid.html'">Paid Projects <i class="fa fa-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn" id="main-menu" onclick="location.href='contact.html'">Contact Us <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-12 pull-right">
            <div class="form-group input-group" style="margin-top:15px;">
                <input id="search" placeholder="Here you search" class="form-control"/>
                <span id="search-icon"class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>                     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- header section - end -->
```

Any questions or issues, please do ask.